# C++ File has 32K ints seperated by newline. I need to create 8 smaller files to each hold 4096 ints

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I have a file of ints seperated by newline delimiter.

```
324872
27
256230
0
45767
276143
4
258283
189
153812
214521
```

The file size is 32768 lines. I need to break it into 8 smaller files of 4096 lines. I use fstream to stream the orginal file into a char buffer:

```
std::string fileOfInts(".txt");
char *buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
std::ifstream inputFromOrigin("origin.txt");
int fileIndex = 0;
while (inputFromOrigin)
{
    inputFromOrigin.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
    size_t count = inputFromOrigin.gcount();
    if (!count)
        break;

    std::ofstream createRunSizeFile;
    createRunSizeFile.open("fileOfInts" + std::to_string(fileIndex) + fileOfInts);
    int value;
    if (createRunSizeFile) {
        for (size_t i = 0, bufferSize = sizeof(buffer); i < bufferSize; i += sizeof(int)) {
            value = (int)buffer[i];
            createRunSizeFile << value << std::endl;
        }
    }
    createRunSizeFile.close();
    fileIndex++;
}
inputFromOrigin.close();
delete[] buffer;
```

But when I extract the ints from the char buffer it only reads two digits at a time and places those two digits in a single file so I end up with 54 files containing one int each:

```
32
```

**UPDATE:**

When I change the for loop that assigns values from the buffer to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
```

I get my 4096 unique lines per file but instead of 8 files with the same values passed in I get 53 files with two digits per line:

```
10
49
57
57
54
48
50
```

How can I parse the char buffer to put 4096 unique ints into each file?

**UPDATE - Solution:**

For others that may have this challenge in the future, here is how I adapted David's solution to my existing code:

```
int fileIndex = 1;
int lineIndex = 0;
std::string line = "";
std::ofstream createRunSizeFile;
// loop through origin file line by line
while (getline(inputFromOrigin, line)) {
    // when file is 0 or 4066 lines long create a new file
    if (lineIndex % RUN == 0) {
        createRunSizeFile.open("fileOfInts" + std::to_string(fileIndex) + fileOfInts);
        lineIndex = 0;
        if (createRunSizeFile.is_open()) {
            createRunSizeFile.close();
        }
        // open new run size file and increment file counter
        createRunSizeFile.open("fileOfInts" + std::to_string(fileIndex++) + fileOfInts);
        if (!createRunSizeFile.good()) {
            std::cerr << "Error: Run Size File Failed to Open" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    // assign line from origin to the run size file
    createRunSizeFile << line << std::endl;
    lineIndex++;
}
inputFromOrigin.close();
```

I made the false assumption that it would be easier to extract the ints from a char buffer than just going line by line. This solution does exactly what I need it to do now.

Comment: Lots of contradictory statements in the question. 2^3 is 8. Do you want files of size 8 bytes or 4096 bytes? Then in the end you say you want 4096 `int`s in each file? That's more than 4096 bytes. Please be specific.

Comment: You say the input is a text file, but you read it like it's a binary file (and even that, incorrectly). Which way is it?

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` == `sizeof(char *)` == 4 (or 8), not `BUFFER_SIZE`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you are right, it's a bit of a mess, i've tried a variety of approaches and this is the cloeset I've gotten. My original file containt 32K individual ints. I want to create 8 seperate files ot 4096 individual ints.

Comment: It is possible that my problem is streaming into the char buffer and not just streaming into a new file, but I have had better luck so far with this.

Comment: Since you are using `fstream`, your **text** file will contain integers of different lengths `1 - 11` **characters** each (including room for the `+/-`). You cannot rely on any number of bytes to locate and split the file. You will simply have to keep a line counter and read each line. It is up to you whether you buffer the lines or simply write them out as you read them (the easy way). With 32K, it doesn't really matter, with 32B it would. Just open a file for writing, read 4k/write 4k close output file, open next, repeat.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use [`split(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html)?

Comment: @CarlNorum its a good idea, but I'm not sure how I would implement that in this case. I need to make 8 files each with 4096 lines out of one file with 32768 lines. If you have an example I'd love to see it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that is exactly what I tried to do in the beginning, was to just write directly to a new file without a buffer. My problem was that getting my loop to iterate over a dynamic number of files wasn't working without using a buffer. Now that I have a buffer that helps me create the new file, I'm having trouble extracting my data from the buffer. I'm sure there is something I'm missing about writing a portion directly to a file that would make this problem go away.

Comment: Just `split -l 4096` should do it. Am I missing something>?

Comment: @CarlNorum is that Boost? I'm not familiar with that library

Comment: It's a posix command line utility. Just seems like you're trying to solve an already solved problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `.read`, simply use `getline` to read a line containing an integer into a string. Then it is just a matter of keeping a line-counter and coming up with some scheme to write a suffix for an output filename and opening the output file and writing your `4096` lines to the file, resetting the line-counter, opening the next file and repeating until you run out of lines to read.

You can either `#define` a constant for the number of lines per sub-file or declare one, then declare your counters (below `fileno` is just used as the sub-file suffix), declare a string to use as a buffer to hold the line read from input and then your two files -- opening the input file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define NLINES 4096     /* constant no. of lines for output subfiles */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate at least 1 argument for filename */
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }

    size_t  n = 0,              /* line counter */
            fileno = 1;         /* output file suffix */
    std::string s {};           /* string to use as buffer */
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);  /* open input file stream */
    std::ofstream subf;         /* output file stream */

    if (!f.good()) { /* validate input file stream stat/e good */
        std::cerr << "error: input file open failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

To split the file, simply read each line into `s` and check whether the *modulo* of your line counter is zero. If so, create your next output filename, reset your line-counter zero, check whether your output file is open and if so, close it, then open the output file using the new output filename, validate it is open, then it is simply writing the string to your output file and incrementing your line-counter, e.g.

```
    while (getline (f, s)) {        /* read each line from input file into s */
        if (n % NLINES == 0) {      /* if 0 or 4096 */
            /* create output filename "subfile_X" */
            std::string fname = { "subfile_" + std::to_string(fileno++) };
            n = 0;                  /* reset line count 0 */
            if (subf.is_open())     /* if output file open - close it */
                subf.close();
            subf.open (fname);      /* open new output file */
            if (!subf.good()) {     /* validate output file stream state good */
                std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << fname << "'.\n";
                return 1;
            }
        }
        subf << s << '\n';      /* write s to output file */
        n++;                    /* increment line count */
    }
```

That is really all you need. Sewing the parts together would give the complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define NLINES 4096     /* constant no. of lines for output subfiles */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate at least 1 argument for filename */
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }

    size_t  n = 0,              /* line counter */
            fileno = 1;         /* output file suffix */
    std::string s {};           /* string to use as buffer */
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);  /* open input file stream */
    std::ofstream subf;         /* output file stream */

    if (!f.good()) { /* validate input file stream stat/e good */
        std::cerr << "error: input file open failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (getline (f, s)) {        /* read each line from input file into s */
        if (n % NLINES == 0) {      /* if 0 or 4096 */
            /* create output filename "subfile_X" */
            std::string fname = { "subfile_" + std::to_string(fileno++) };
            n = 0;                  /* reset line count 0 */
            if (subf.is_open())     /* if output file open - close it */
                subf.close();
            subf.open (fname);      /* open new output file */
            if (!subf.good()) {     /* validate output file stream state good */
                std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << fname << "'.\n";
                return 1;
            }
        }
        subf << s << '\n';      /* write s to output file */
        n++;                    /* increment line count */
    }
}
```

**Example Input File with 32k Integers**

```
$ wc -l < dat/32kint.txt
32768
```

**Example Use**

Not very exiting:

```
$ ./bin/filesplit dat/32kint.txt
```

**Resulting Subfiles**

```
$ for i in subfile*; do printf "%s - " "$i"; wc -l < "$i"; done
subfile_1 - 4096
subfile_2 - 4096
subfile_3 - 4096
subfile_4 - 4096
subfile_5 - 4096
subfile_6 - 4096
subfile_7 - 4096
subfile_8 - 4096
```

Eight files of `4096` lines each. Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This worked fine, I was easily able to adapt it to my code. This was the first approach I tried on this problem and I couldn't get it to work, I may have to review my repo and see what I was doing wrong. Thanks for taking the time to work out a solution.